Regressing a stationary variable on an overdifferenced variable
Section 9.1 of Forecasting: Principles and Practice (2nd edition) discusses estimation of dynamic regression models (regression with ARIMA errors). The authors write:

An important consideration when estimating a regression with ARMA errors is that all of the variables in the model must first be stationary. Thus, we first have to check that $y_t$ and all of the predictors $(x_{1,t},\dots,x_{k,t})$ appear to be stationary. If we estimate the model when any of these are non-stationary <...> [we] first difference the non-stationary variables in the model.
It is often desirable to maintain the form of the relationship between $y_t$ and the predictors, and consequently it is common to difference all of the variables if any of them need differencing. The resulting model is then called a “model in differences”, as distinct from a “model in levels”, which is what is obtained when the original data are used without differencing.

(Emphasis is mine)
I am instinctively skeptical of differencing variables that do not contain unit roots, and I do not think it would be a great idea to difference a stationary dependent variable (or would it?). However, in this case I do not see an obvious problem with differencing a stationary regressor (predictor). Thus my questions: If $y_t$ contains a unit root while $x_t$ is stationary,

Is there anything that will go wrong when we regress $\Delta y_t$ on $\Delta x_t$?
Does the answer depend on whether we allows for ARMA errors?

Of course, there are always things that can go wrong, but here I mean specifically the ones that would be caused by $\Delta x_t$ being overdifferenced.

Somewhat related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303019/what-is-an-integrated-time-series/303273#303273 - differencing I(0) series leads to zero long-run variance, which is a bad omen for constructing, e.g., test statistics

@ChristophHanck, that is a great reference. I had forgotten about that thread and your answer there.

FWIW, experimenting with library(sandwich) n <- 1e6 y <- rnorm(n-1) x <- diff(rnorm(n)) limo <- lm(y~x-1) kernHAC(limo, sandwich = F) does not suggest an immediate issue.
