ARIMAX specifying xreg
I want to proxy the state of the economy in my arimax(p=?, d=1, q=?) model  via GDP.
Should I use absolute values or relative changes for fitting my model? Does the implementation of arima built this first difference on xreg automatically when specifying d = 1 or am I expected to do this myself?
arima(z_values, order = c(p, 1, q), xreg = gdp_absolut)

arima(z_values, order = c(p, 1, q), xreg = gdp_relative_change)

The documentation says:

xreg Optionally, a vector or matrix of external regressors, which must have the same number of rows as x.

source: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/arima
I guess it needs to be gdp_absolut, else it would have one less row than z_values Correct?

Maybe this will help:
https://otexts.com/fpp2/estimation.html

Thank you! I get the same feeling from this, that gdp_absolut makes more sense, but still would apreciate a proper explenation, since I could not find a section specifically saying that...

Also related (and with an active bounty): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/656252

Note that arima() fits a regression on xreg with ARIMA errors. Thus it does not difference the predictors in any way. It simply regresses the observations on the features, then fits an ARIMA model on the residuals. Simply keep this in mind when deciding how you want to model.

That's not quite true. If the ARIMA model contains differencing, then the estimation involves applying that differencing operator to both the variable to be forecast and all predictors, resulting in ARMA errors. The resulting model is equivalent to a regression using the undifferenced variables with ARIMA errors. Estimation of the model is done in a single optimization, with regression coefficients and ARMA coefficients estimated simultaneously.

@RobHyndman: thank you, then I have been misunderstanding your blog post for a long time. Will try to keep that in mind.
